# How to convert a "dataframe" from SQL?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I'm importing a dataframe from SQL into Jupyter with the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                      'Server=SERVE_RNAME;'
                      'Database=DB_NAME;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=no;'
                      'UID=USER'
                      'PWD=PASSWORD')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
 SOME SQL QUERY (THAT I CANNOT CHANGE) GIVEN TO ME BY MY BOSS
''')

df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
conn.close()
```

The issue is that when I want to see the `df` I get

```py
df.head()

0   [2, 1098002, 19-01-2018, MEXN, SNLP, 19-01-201...
1   [2, 1069341, 29-01-2018, VALL, GDLJ, 29-01-201...
2   [2, 1074115, 31-01-2018, MEXN, GDLJ, 31-01-201...
3   [2, 1054977, 06-01-2018, GDLJ, VALL, 06-01-201...
4   [2, 1110098, 17-01-2018, MORE, MEXN, 17-01-201...
```

So I don't know what's going on here: Is it a problem with my code or with the query?

In any case how do I correct it to get a proper dataframe? (The solution may be my correcting my code or by manipulating the dataframe I already have).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Also, it suck that you can't change SQL - if you find room to improve the query performance, DO IT. Show your boss the results - not the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply use read_sql() for reading data database

```
df=pd.read_sql(sql,con)
```

[see more about documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)